# Is it safe and correct to run Drush under the same user account that the webserver runs on?

Tags: drush

I've found following informaion:

> It's usually considered best practice to run Drush under the same user account that the webserver runs on (such as www-data). Some modules, such as XML Sitemap, Advanced Aggregator and cTools, often try to alter or generate files.

I also have some problem with Ctools cache.
I can use following command to run Drush under the www-data user:
`sudo -u www-data drush....`

But is it safe and correct to run Drush under the same user account that the webserver runs on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the answer is "yes", it is safe and correct.  However, the specific answer here depends on (a) your security policy, and (b) what you want to do with Drush.  Some people prefer to make the code files not writable by the web server.  If you had a setup like that, then you would not be able to run `drush dl` as the webserver user.

The other thing of note here is that any time you run any Drush command, all Drush commandfiles are given the opportunity to alter the command's behavior.  This means that it is generally NOT considered safe to run drush via `sudo` to root, unless you trust all of the code in your Drupal site to run as the root user.  This is not generally a concern for `sudo -u www-data`, though, as you are already trusting the code in your Drupal site to run as the web user.

Comment: I understand now that sometimes I can run Drush under www-data user (for example, some scripts for Munin monitoring). But during usual everyday work it is acceptable to run Drush under my personal user. ty.

Comment: On my dev machine, I make all of my webserver files owned by my personal login account, and set their group to www-data, and use g+w on directories that are writable by the webserver. In this environment, I run Drush as my personal login user, pretty much with no trouble. Files created by the webserver will be owned by the webserver, so sometimes I cannot change these w/out chown, but this is not often a problem.